# Looping to grab HTML calendar date data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, custom-data-attribute

I am manipulating a WordPress calendar plugin. I'm trying to add some CSS to the dates on the calendar for every day up to the current date. The plugin that I'm using, has the calendar in a table. The code for an individual day looks like this:

```
<td class="day-with-date" data-date="2017-5-10">
  <div class="day-number">10</div>
</td>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to loop through the dates from the data attribute.

This is my script.

```
    $('.day-with-date .day-number').each(function(element){

    var dataNumber = "[data-date=" + $(this).text() + "]"; 
    var dataDateDay = "[data-date="+day+"]";        
    var textDay = $(this).text();

    if(textDay <= day){

        $('td.day-with-date .day-number').addClass('online-display');

    }else if(textDay > day){

        $('td.day-with-date .day-number').removeClass('online-display');

    }else{
        console.log("error douche");
    }

});
```

What it's doing, is adding the CSS because textDay is <= than day. But it's removing the class after it's applied. I'm trying to get the CSS to add for all days up to today's date, then remove the CSS for days after.

How can I loop through the calendar dates, then apply my CSS class to all days up to the current date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your data-date were in ISOFormat then you could simply stick it in a new Date() and compare it to the current date to know if it was a past date or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be a change in your [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

```
$('.day-with-date .day-number').each(function(index) {

  var dataNumber = "[data-date=" + $(this).text() + "]";
  var dataDateDay = "[data-date=" + day + "]";
  var textDay = $(this).text();

  if (textDay <= day) {
    $(this).addClass('online-display');
  } else if (textDay > day) {
    $(this).removeClass('online-display');
  } else {
    console.log("error douche");
  }
});
```

You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/k99o5b39/

Comment: @TheManThatDoesn'tKnowJack glad to hear it solved the problem. If it is the right answer then just mark it as resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
... // day has been defined

$('.day-with-date .day-number').each(function(element){

  var parsedDay = Number.parseInt(element.text());
  if(parsedDay <= day){
      element.addClass('online-display');
  } else {
      element.removeClass('online-display');
  }
});
```